# Propensity Score Matching using MatchIt. How to introduce a caliper to an exact additional specification

Tags: r, propensity-score-matching

I'm new to R, and Im using matchit to match patients by propensity scores. My dataset includes two groups of patients that differ by whether or not they received a drug.  As well as matching on propensity score, I also want to exact match on age, gender and family practice, as the decision to treat does vary significantly depending on these characteristics.

My problem is that I would like to exact match by age ± 2 years, as I would like to increase the number of treated patients that can be matched in my dataset, by increasing the flexibility of my exact matches (rather than using an arbitrary cut-off, as with an categorical age variable, for example).

The code below works well

```
match.1 <-  matchit(exposed ~ imd2010_5 + hyp + mhealth + mm_score + GP_consult + smoke + no_pres3m + lterm_pres + pres_rate, 
data=dataset_pscore2, 
distance=dataset_pscore2$pscores, 
method="nearest", 
exact=c("gender", "pracid", "age_cat"), 
discard="both", 
caliper=0.25, 
ratio=2)
```

Id just like to change the exact code to something like

```
exact=c("gender", "pracid", "age" *with a caliper*),
```

Is this possible?

Comment: This cannot be done with `MatchIt`. You should look into the package `designmatch`, which was written precisely for these problems where complicated constraints are desired.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i can tell, Propensity Score Matching (PSM) usually uses a LOGIT regression to find the estimated propensity scores, as a way to avoid the **curse of dimensionality**.So, doing exact matching in some covariates in a PSM set-up sounds unlikely.

I suggest running two matching procedures: The first one with exact matching on the covariates which you would like to be exact matched. Then, running the PSM on the new matched-sample on the other covariates.

As an example:

```r
match.1 <-  matchit(exposed ~ gender + pracid + age_cat, 
data=dataset_pscore2, 
method="exact")

matched_sample <- match.data(match.1) # Get Propensity Scores for 'matched_sample'

match.2 <-  matchit(exposed ~ imd2010_5 + hyp + mhealth + mm_score + GP_consult + smoke + no_pres3m + lterm_pres + pres_rate, 
data=matched_sample, 
distance=matched_sample2$pscores, 
method="nearest", 
discard="both", 
caliper=0.25, 
ratio=2)
```

I also suggest reading the [MatchIt](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MatchIt/vignettes/matchit.pdf) package documentation. And this other wonderfull package, called [cem](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cem/vignettes/cem.pdf).

Comment: MatchIt even has an own website now: https://kosukeimai.github.io/MatchIt/

Answer (score 0):

You can now (as of `matchIt` version 4.0.0) supply specific covariates to the caliper` argument to request calipers on them directky in the context of another matching method. For you example, this owuld look like this:

```
match.1 <-  matchit(exposed ~ imd2010_5 + hyp + mhealth + mm_score + GP_consult + smoke + no_pres3m + lterm_pres + pres_rate, 
                    data=dataset_pscore2, 
                    distance=dataset_pscore2$pscores, 
                    method="nearest", 
                    exact=c("gender", "pracid"), 
                    discard="both", 
                    caliper=c(0.25, age = 2),
                    std.caliper = c(TRUE, FALSE),
                    ratio=2)
```

The key lines are `caliper=c(0.25, age = 2)` and `std.caliper = c(TRUE, FALSE)`. The `caliper` line says that we want a caliper of .25 on the distance measure (i.e., the propensity score) and a caliper of 2 on `age`. The `std.caliper` line says that we want the first caliper to be in standard deviation units and the second caliper to be in raw units. This way, you have that units must be within .25 standard deviations of the propensity score and within 2 years of age to be able to be matched with each other. See the documentation at `help("method_nearest", package = "MatchIt")` for details and an example.